# Computing slope of data with correlated errors using Monte Carlo method

Tags: regression, correlation, monte-carlo

I have $N$ pairs of $(x,y)$ measurements. I have the (estimated) uncertainty of each $y$ value as well as the correlations between each pair of $y$ values.

I want to know whether there is a significant slope in these data. I am thinking of doing this using a Monte Carlo simulation. In particular, I plan to obtain a random realization of the $y$ values, regress $y$ on $x$, calculate the slope, and repeat (say) 10000 times. Then I can make a histogram of slopes and see whether it overlaps with nil.

Does this strategy make sense? Is there anything I am overlooking?

Comment: Why do you want to use a Monte Carlo simulation? It would probably be much more computationally expensive than a linear regression with correlated errors (or not?)?